# In jssor, is it possible to prevent download of images

Tags: download, right-click, jssor

jssor looks good, but I need a solution where people cannot right-click and save an image.  Ideally, they should also not be able inspect the source and figure out the uri of the photo - but I can possibly live without this.

Are either or both of the above available or implementable in jssor?  Can I add another plugin or code to jssor to disable right-click/download of images?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider1_container").contextmenu(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: What is the above about?  Do I insert this code in jssor?  Where?  Remember, I have not even downloaded it, I am just evaluating it.

Comment: To download a image in a page, you need to right click on the element and click 'same image as' menu item on the context menu. If you disable the context menu, there is no way to download image for an user. The script above enables you to disable context menu on some element.